# How to display latest comments on wordpress homepage?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, comments

I'm using facebook comments for wordpress. This plugin is doing the job. 
But to up the interaction a bit, I want people to see other people's reactions. 
Basically if (say Sally says: Cool to a post about posters) I want her reaction to display on my homepage.

Sally: 
Cool on "poster foto"

Something like that. 
When I go to my comment moderation tool in facebook apps, i see the list of comments. 
Something similar but public and on my homepage?

Any idea's please?

Answer (score 0):

You'll basically need to build your own tools for this.  Facebook's widgets can simplify the process, if you listen to the callback when users write comments in the comment widget.  But otherwise, up to you to store the data, aggregate and curate it.